# Why does VBA keep going before a query is done refreshing?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have the following code refreshing 1 or 2 queries, depending:

```
Sub RefreshPowerQueries()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim startTime As Single

startTime = Timer

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Application.Calculate
If WB.Names("One_Or_Two_Queries_Boolean").RefersToRange.Value2 Then
    WB.Connections("Query - 1").Refresh
    WB.Connections("Query - 2").Refresh
    shIndiv.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    shIndiv.Columns("Z").Hidden = True
Else
    WB.Connections("Query - 3").Refresh
    shIndiv2.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    shIndiv2.Columns("Z").Hidden = True
    shIndiv2.Select
End If

MsgBox "Load Time: " & Format((Timer - startTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

When it goes through the Else part of the statement, it waits until the table is full refreshed, then properly re-aligns everything, then generates how long it took. Great, it works perfectly (And takes ~6 seconds).

However, when I go through the True portion of the IF, it takes about 1 second to run, but the queries aren't done updating. It'll then have the queries refreshing in the background, and after some time, they'll refresh - after the resize portion is done.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to force the queries to finish refreshing before continuing on?

Thank you

Comment: Check whether "Query - 1" and "Query -2" are configured for "background refresh", which implies they're running asynchronously.

Comment: That solved it!